# exporting and running a jar

Tags: java, jar

I wish to export a rather big jar - which has many dependencies from eclipse.
I should also mention that my classpath differs from my buildpath, and on export I would like the classpath files to be exported as well as exporting it with the proper "Running configuration".

So may questions:
1. How can I export the classpath jars with my jar? Should I replace the builfpath entries with the classpath's?
2. Any quick way to get this done?
3. When I run the resulting jar - should I just run it "java -jar myJar.jar"? Or do I need to specify a "-classpath ..." as well to reference it to the other jars? (Note: on eclipse I am using - the export all jars option + I choose the runtime configuration and at the end result I can see a manifest file containg information).

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You export as a Runnable Jar in Eclipse. and then run as

```
java - jar <filename>.jar
```

Comment: Thank you, but my questions refers to jar dependencies, not the actual running command. I mentioned I have many dependencies on my classpath - and was wondering how to export using these dependencies, either on export time or run time.

Comment: In eclipse when you export as a runnable jar (not simple jar), all the dependencies gets exported with the runnable jar. you will notice that the file size of this jar is much larger than your class or other jar's. This is because all dependencies are exported with it.